# Visual studio 2019 not recognising #include <iostream>

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I just installed vs 2019 using the installer. I installed only the component for C++ programming because I needed it for only console programs. I was surprised that the compiler did not recognize any header file. What could be wrong? Will downloading and installing visual C++ redistributable resolve the problem?

Comment: No idea, but have you checked the common suspects,  such as restarting the computer?

Comment: Selecting the "Desktop development with C++" option during installation should be sufficient for a working C++ environment. The redistributable doesn't apply as it's the runtime libraries.

Comment: You might have created a non C++ project or something. 2019 version requires you to use "pch.h" if you played with it or the project definitions you could've gotten weird errors.

Comment: If you are using `#include "pch.h"` make sure that it is above all non-comment lines in your source file. If you put any line above it like `#include <iostream>` the compiler will completely ignore the line as it does all lines above `#include "pch.h"`

Comment: After reading the previous comments, U should provide a code clarifying your issue

Comment: I voted to close this question because with the current contents there is no way to possibly answer the question without guessing.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you may likely missing `$(IncludePath)` within Properties->VC++ Directories->Include Directories. Adding this should make iostream and others visible again. You probably deleted it by mistake while setting up your program.